# Posts are not showing up on next page.

Tags: posts, loop, pages, pagination

I am using WordPress 'wp_page_numbers' plugin and the next pages are empty. I'm not sure what's going on with my code but it's suppose to start over again on the next page. Here is what I have............................

```
<div class="container post_container" id="blog_post_container">

 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="running_head_pink" id="recent_posts">
    <h1>Recent Posts</h1>
    </div>

    <?php 

      $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
      $recentPost = new WP_Query(

            array(
                'type' => 'post',
                'posts_per_page' => 6,
                'order' => 'ASC',
                'orderby' => 'date',
                'cat' => '39',
                'paged' => $paged

            )

            );

        if(have_posts()) { ?>
    <br>
    <br>

    <div class=" row posts_table">

        <?php 

        $counter = 0;

        while($recentPost->have_posts()) {

        $recentPost->the_post();


                ?>

        <div class="col-xs-4 recent-blog-posts" id='border-right'>



            <div class="recent-thumbnail"><?php echo the_post_thumbnail('medium') ?><h3 style="color:pink; font-family:Anton, sans-serif;"><?php echo get_the_date('n.d.y'); ?></h3></div>
            <h2 class="blog-title" id="container_titles"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
            <br>
            <p>
            <!-- <?php echo get_the_excerpt() ?> -->
            <a class="ghost-button" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read</a>


        </p>

        <hr style='border-color:pink'>




        </div>



        <?php 

        $counter++;

        if($counter %3 == 0) {
            ?>

                    </div>
        <div class="row posts_table">


        <?php

        }   

                }

                  wp_reset_postdata();

             ?>

             </div>

             <?php

              if(function_exists('wp_page_numbers')) { wp_page_numbers();  


            }


            }

            ?>

        </div>
    </div>
    </div>


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, that plugin hasn't been updated in **8 years** (https://wordpress.org/plugins-wp/wp-page-numbers/). George W. Bush was still president when that code was written. You should never use plugins that are not actively maintained because they most likely won't work. Try wp_page-navi (https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-pagenavi/). It's actively developed/maintained.